# How to sort a json object by numeric sorting method

Tags: javascript, angular

I am having an object with the display value as a string having numbers in it 
I want the values to be sorted by Numeric sorting and not alphabetic sorting

```
Let jsonObj = [{ displayValue : 'B1'}, {displayValue : 'A3'},{ displayValue : 'D1'}, {displayValue : 'C2'}, {displayValue: 'A4'}, {displayValue: 'D3'}];
```

so the output should have 
B1, D1, C2, A3, A4

Can any one help me out with the logic for numeric sorting
Any help is appreciated

Thanks in Advance

Comment: That is not JSON. It is a JavaScript object literal.

Comment: You have several tasks here: (1) extract the property values into an array. (2) sort that array. So this question is too broad. If you can solve (1) then your question should be just about (2), providing an array with strings (but then it is a duplicate question). If you cannot solve (1), then don't mention the sorting (but then again it is a duplicate question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will sort the array as you want:

```
array.sort((a, b) => +a.displayValue.match(/\d+/)[0] - +b.displayValue.match(/\d+/)[0] > 0 ? 1 : -1);
```